# Setting badge in chrome extension works in dev mode but not in prod (chrome store)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have problems with changing badge value on every content load (page change). Weird thing is that everyting works on dev mode and badge value is chaning but when I developed app to the store badge doesnt't change on every content load. Why?

Here's a little bit code from content.js

```
  function hideComments(comments, users) {
    let deletedComments = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < comments.length; i++)
      for (let j = 0; j < users.length; j++)
      //user is ALWAYS at [2] index in the array
        if(comments[i].children[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase().split(',')[2].trim() === users[j]) {
          comments[i].style.display = 'none';
          deletedComments++;
        }
    //send number of deleted comments to the background
    if(deletedComments !== 0)
      return chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: `${deletedComments}`});
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: ''});
  }

  if(blockedUsers === null)
    localStorage.setItem('blockedUsers', '');

  blockedUsers = localStorage.getItem('blockedUsers');

  if(blockedUsers.length) {
    //function expects an array as 2nd parameter
    hideComments(commentsNodes,  blockedUsers.split(','));
  }
```

Like I said before. If I have.. lets say 2 users added, the badge value is changing to 5 if there are 5 comments exist or badge is set to empty string (to hide it) if there's none. It works perfectly on dev mode but not when app is added to the store.

> background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [238, 50, 78, 255] });
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: message.data});
  });
 });
```

Comment: https://github.com/XaooB/block-user-chrome-extension - here's the whole app.

Comment: Aha! The background.js code reveals the problem in your script. Move chrome.runtime.onMessage into the top scope. Each API listener must be registered on each run of the background script.

Comment: Works the same on dev mode like it used to but I'll publish it and then we will see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: In dev mode onInstalled is triggered every time apparently.

Comment: I hope ure right.